# passing JSON from ASIHTTPRequest to django

Tags: objective-c, django, json, nsdictionary, asihttprequest

I've exhausted other threads, so I'm posting this question here.  Please pardon any newbie mistakes I've made along the way.  I've been reading a lot, and I think I'm getting confused.

The Goal:
I'm trying to pass data from a form in objective-c to my django web service.  In an effort to assist with this, I've employed the `ASIHTTPRequest` class to facilitate information transfer.  Once sent to the web service, I'd like to save that data to my sqlite3 database.

Procedure:
On the Objective-C side:
I've stored the inputted form data and their respective keys in an NSDictionary, like this:

```
NSDictionary *personInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:firstName.text, @"fName", middleName.text, @"mName", lastName.text, @"lName", nil];
```

I've added it to my ASIHTTPRequest in a different class by using a delegate.  I've made the NSDictionary the same as above in the code block below for simplicity, like so:

```
NSString *jsonPerson = [personInfo JSONRepresentation];
[request addRequestHeader: @"Content-Type" value:@"application/json; charset=utf-8"];
[request appendPostData:[jsonPerson dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"]; 
[request startAsynchronous];
```

And a NSLog shows the string I'm passing to look like this, which validates at least in [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

```
{"mName":"Arthur","lName":"Smith","fName":"Bob"}
```

Because I'm seeing what appears to be valid JSON coming from my ASIHTTPRequest, and actions are running from requestfinished: rather than requestfailed:, I'm making the assumption that the problem more than likely isn't on the Objective-C side, but rather on the django side.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
json.loads(request.POST)
>>expected string or buffer

json.loads('request.POST')
>>no JSON object to decode

json.loads(request.raw_post_data)
>>mNamelNamefName

incoming = request.POST
>>{"mName":"Arthur","lName":"Smith","fName":"Bob"}

incoming = request.POST
onlyValues = incoming.iterlists()
>>(u'{"mName":"Arthur","lName":"Smith","fName":"Bob"}', [u''])
```

...and a smattering of other seemingly far-fetched variations.  I've kept a log, and can elaborate.  The only hope I've been able to find is in the last example; it looks like it's treating the entire string as the key, rather than breaking up each dict object and key as I would have expected.

I realize this is terribly elementary and I don't normally ask, but this problem has me particularly stumped.  I do also remember reading somewhere that python won't recognize the double-quotes around each object and key, that to get it to something django likes, each should be surrounded by single-quotes.  I just don't have any idea how to get them that way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a little cumbersome but you may try some simple regexp in `objective c` just to see if that is really the case

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\"" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *json = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:jsonPerson options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [jsonPerson length]) withTemplate:@"'"];
```

There might be some errors because I didn't run the code.

Comment: Your code is correct - an NSLog of your json string yields single quotes around both objects and keys.  I'm still thinking the problem lies on the Django side, and how I'm trying to parse that data.  Thanks for the response, though.

Comment: Okay so you can also check out the exact response that is coming to serser-side django. If it is surrounded by "" then that might be the reason why django does not treat it as JSON.

Comment: I don't know python so I might be totally wrong with this, but from what I see the POST response on server side is an array of unicode strings (two times u''), so you may want to use [request setPostValue:[jsonPerson dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] forKey:@"person"]; instead of appendPostData to eliminate the array problem. Then just use 'person' field from the post array.

Comment: This wasn't the exact solution I used, but this got me thinking in the right direction.  Thanks.